# NuGet error during installing packages "Extensibility DTE object unavailable"

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

I'm trying to install a package on the Visual Studio 2012 environment using NuGet. For at least two packages (EntityFramework and nLog) I'm getting following error:

> Install failed. Rolling back...
>
> Extensibility DTE object unavailable.

Visual Studio is running as an administrator. Operating system is Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise. I use NuGet 2.0.30625.9003.

Moreover when VS is starting it throws following exception:

[image: error]

Advises I have found on the Internet to run devenv /ResetSettings or devenv /ResetSkipPkgs and then devenv /Setup but none of this has solved the issue in my case. Is there any way to mend it without re installing VS?

Comment: Try updating NuGet to the latest version. The version you're running is pretty old. Even if it won't help, it's a good idea to update it.

Comment: Thank you @DamirArh it has helped. Even the error message about the menu package has disappeared. You could post an answer so I could accept it.

Comment: I've posted my comment as the answer,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating NuGet to the latest version. The version you're running is pretty old. Even if it won't help, it's a good idea to update it.